# Implementing follower system using a many to many field through a model

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am adding a following/follower system and I made it a foreign field in my profile model. The thing is, I want to be able to save multiple information to it like the time when a particular user started following and other future info, so I made the many to many field pass through a model, as shown here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships

Please, I will like to know what I am missing as I am getting

```
AttributeError at /api/opeyemi-odedeyi-ikx5yh/follow/
'User' object has no attribute 'following'
```

I have tried this:

models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    SEX= (
    ('M', 'Male'),
    ('F', 'Female'),
    )

    user          = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='profiles')
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(blank=True, verbose_name="DOB", null=True)
    bio           = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    sex           = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=SEX, blank=True, null=True)
    following     = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True, through='Follow', related_name='followed_by')
    updated_on    = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.fullname

class Follow(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='user_following')
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='profile')
    date_followed = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
```

serializers.py

```
class ProfileDetailedSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.SlugRelatedField(read_only=True, slug_field='slug')
    age = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)

    following = serializers.SlugRelatedField(read_only=True, slug_field='slug', many=True)
    following_count = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    user_has_followed = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = "__all__"

        read_only_fields = ('pk', 'user')

    def get_age(self, instance):
        today = date.today()
        dob = instance.date_of_birth
        if dob==None:
            return None
        return today.year - dob.year - ((today.month, today.day) < (dob.month, dob.day))

    def get_following_count(self, instance):
        return instance.following.count()

    def get_user_has_followed(self, instance):
        request = self.context.get("request")
        return instance.following.filter(pk=request.user.pk).exists()
```

views.py

```
class UserFollowAPIView(APIView):
    '''
    Can follow(post) and unfollow(delete) the user
    '''
    serializer_class = ProfileDetailedSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def delete(self, request, slug):
        followUser = get_object_or_404(User, slug=slug)
        user = self.request.user

        followUser.following.remove(user)
        followUser.save()

        serializer_context = {"request": request}
        serializer = self.serializer_class(followUser, context=serializer_context)

        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

    def post(self, request, slug):
        followUser = get_object_or_404(User, slug=slug)
        user = self.request.user

        followUser.following.add(user)
        followUser.save()

        serializer_context = {"request": request}
        serializer = self.serializer_class(followUser, context=serializer_context)

        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

urls.py

```
path("<slug:slug>/follow/", UserFollowAPIView.as_view(), name="user-follow"),
```

Note:

I used slug because I am not using username in my app, so I had a slug field and made it the lookup field instead of the normal pk

The serializer_context is so the user cannot follow when it returns true (i.e they cannot follow twice)

Comment: Does the `User` class come from a library, or is it something you implemented?

Comment: I used Django-rest-auth for that

Comment: Okay. What do you understand from the error message? Have you tried to narrow down the issue?

Comment: I have no idea which is why I was asking, its the first time I am using a many to many fields through another model

Comment: you're accessing the `following` field in the wrong place - it's a field of the `Profile` model, not the `User`. So you should do something like `followUser.profiles.following...`

Comment: @henriquesalvaro i am not sure i understand

Comment: `followUser` in the code you shared is an instance of the `User` class. You are declaring the field `following     = models.ManyToManyField...` on the `Profile` class. The error you're getting is literally due to the fact that you are trying to access a field (attribute) that does not exist on the `User` class.